# Fill out input field with code doesn't trigger onChange functions

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on customJs for swagger.
There I want to fill out an input field in advance for my use case.

Basically I can't see the code attached to the input field generated by swagger, but I can fill the input field with `inputElement.setAttribute('value',"some stuff" )`

But this does not trigger function as it seems, because when I proceed to use the submit button, it says the field is empty, only after I `MANUALLY` typed a letter and removed it, it recognized my changes.

Can I somehow trigger whatever the underlying function might be?

Comment: Why not call the onchange function after you set the attribute?

Comment: You should be able to call the function to trigger it. But you will need to go in and determine what that function is

Comment: Guess I will just trial and error to find it, was more wondering if there was something like `fillOutAsHuman` to bypass that haha but thx